# Is there any keyboard that has got Artificial Intelligence to play Chords based on the notes played on the right hand side?

Tags: chords, accompaniment

Is there any keyboard that has got Artificial Intelligence to play Chords based on the notes played on the right hand side?

I have seen such a Casio Keyboard in my childhood. But have you ever happen to see a modern keyboard with this feature?

So, if i can set my root chord/minor/major, the keyboard will make chord progressions based on the notes we play with the right hand.

Is that invented? should i patent it? he he he..

Comment: Please don't misuse "Artificial Intelligence"

Comment: There is, at least one which uses all notes played on the piano, in particular left hand notes. I think I saw it on a Yamaha e-piano, but I don't know which, nor the name of the feature, thus I only add this as a comment.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This is a proper use of "artificial intelligence." While general AI involves a higher form of problem solving, a special (and therefore more simple) AI may be necessary to adequately analyze/generate a variety of chord progressions/structures (rather than just mirror to a database like traditional algorithms might).

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing this with the feature where auto-accompaniment chords can be defined by simple LH note patterns - holding one note gives that major chord, add one note above for minor, two for 7th, three for m7.   But YOU still have to choose what chord is appropriate.  This is available on plenty of current keyboards, in all price ranges.   Like all auto-accompaniment features it can be helpful, or horrific.   If I had a gig playing for ballroom dancing I might be tempted to buy one. But when I want MY arrangement, MY bassline etc. it sends me mad!